# How are static globals handled in multiple modules?

Tags: c, plugins, static, global

In C, declaring a variable `static` at the global level (outside any function) indicates that it is visible only to that linker object  (typically, that .C file).

If the same .C file is part of multiple different libraries that are then linked together in a single executable, do conflicts arise?

For example:

### MyFile.c

```
typedef struct {
   [my important data];
} MyGlobalType;

static MyGlobalType globalData = { [...data...] };
```

Then if I have:

**Plugin_Alpha.so**: *composed of MyFile.C + AlphaSource.C*
**Plugin_Beta.so**: *composed of MyFile.C + BetaSource.C*
**MainProgram.exe**: *composed of MainCode.C (which loads the two plugins)*

Will Plugin_Alpha and Plugin_Beta have separate, isolated copies of `globalData`?
Or will they end up referring to the same structure?

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's one way to find out:

File `liba.c`:

```
static int globalData;

int *GetGlobalData() { return &globalData; }
```

Compile into two separate shared libraries:

```
$ gcc liba.c -o liba.so -fPIC -shared
$ gcc liba.c -o libb.so -fPIC -shared
```

Main program:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Error checking omitted for expository purposes

  void *liba = dlopen("liba.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  void *libb = dlopen("libb.so", RTLD_LAZY);

  typedef int* (*FuncV_IP)(void);
  FuncV_IP funca = (FuncV_IP)dlsym(liba, "GetGlobalData");
  FuncV_IP funcb = (FuncV_IP)dlsym(libb, "GetGlobalData");

  printf("Module A: GetGlobalData() ==> %p\n", funca());
  printf("Module B: GetGlobalData() ==> %p\n", funcb());

  dlclose(liba);
  dlclose(libb);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it:

```
$ gcc main.c -ldl
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

Output:

```
Module A: GetGlobalData() ==> 0x7fa97536d020
Module B: GetGlobalData() ==> 0x7fa97516b020
```

So therefore, each shared library gets its own copy of the global variables.